For which values of $a$ is this Markov Chain irreducible and aperiodic?
The transition matrix is: $$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 1-a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, I know from theory that a chain is irreducible when a state can be reached from any other state (within the chain). So I should probably start by making sure that $1 - a  > 0$ so that we can reach state $2$ from state $1$, because state $2$ can't be reached any other way.
Secondly, a Markov chain is aperiodic if every state has a  period of $1$. I noticed that there are no self loops for any of the states except state $1$, so if $a > 0$ then there is a self loop from state $1$ to itself , which in turn would make the chain aperiodic.
So $α ∈ (0,1)$. Is my reasoning correct?
Thank you for the help!

For the first bit, yes, you are essentially right. To prove this for small chains, I like to enumerate the states (say, as $1,2,3,4,5$), then (assuming you start in the $i$th row and move to the $j$th state with probability as given in the $(i,j)$-entry in the matrix) I draw a diagram of states pointing to their prospective transition destinations:

Here, I've labeled the $a,1-a$ arrows, but all arrows otherwise have a nonzero transition probability. Assuming $a \ne 0,1$, you can show each state is reachable from each other state easily. Note that, though, if $a = 0$, you can still reach $1$ from $1$ ($1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1$), but if $a=1$ you cannot reach $2$ from any state.
Hence we do need $1- a > 0$.

For the second part you are correct and I have no further commentary.

Thanks a lot for the quick answer and help!
